# Is there a way to select each toggle when using Ratchet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ratchet-2

I am dynamically loading a list of classes from a database that the user is supposed to select if they have been completed. I am using Ratchet's toggle to choose the classes and am trying to use a JavaScript function to find which toggles have been toggled -- so far, no luck. I am not very proficient with JavaScript so I apologize if this seems trivial. The function that that I have been trying to use, how the classes are displayed to the webpage, and the contents of the `CSS` that deals with toggles are as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkClasses() {
      var classes = new Array();
      classes.push("COSC120");
      alert(classes[0]);

      $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function()
      {
        classes.push($(this).val());
      });
    }
  </script>
```

writing classes to page:

```
echo '<div class="toggle" id="' .$row['class_id']. '" name="type">';
echo '<div class="toggle-handle"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

css:

```
.toggle {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 74px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 2px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
         -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
              transition-duration: .5s;
      -webkit-transition-property: background-color, border;
         -moz-transition-property: background-color, border;
              transition-property: background-color, border;
    }
    .toggle .toggle-handle {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      left: -1px;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 28px;
      height: 28px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 100px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
         -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
              transition-duration: .5s;
      -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, border, width;
         -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, border, width;
              transition-property:         transform, border, width;
    }
    .toggle:before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 3px;
      right: 11px;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #999;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      content: "no";
    }
    .toggle.active {
      background-color: #ff7e00;
      border: 2px solid #ff7e00;
    }
    .toggle.active .toggle-handle {
      border-color: #ff7e00;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(44px, 0, 0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(44px, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(44px, 0, 0);
    }
    .toggle.active:before {
      right: auto;
      left: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      content: "yes";
    }
    .toggle input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: none;
    }
```

I do not know if more is needed for any assistance, but if so, please ask! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ratchet will add `active` to the class list of the element, so `$('.toggle.active')` will give you an array of the active toggle switches

Comment: Thank you! The `$('.toggle.active')` was the key that I needed. With that and a function I found `var selected = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle.active');` made it work.